# Layout optimisation Android

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I have a `ListView` with the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:inevent="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.estudiotrilha.inevent.view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_events"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true" >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageEventCover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/event_cover"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <com.estudiotrilha.inevent.view.NewTextView
            android:id="@+id/textIsEnrolled"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="ENROLLED"
            android:textColor="@color/infoText"
            inevent:textFor="small"
            android:background="@color/infoBoxRed"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/event_mark"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <com.estudiotrilha.inevent.view.NewTextView 
                android:id="@+id/textEventName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lisbon Challenge"
                inevent:textFor="h3"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageCalendar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textEventName"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/facebookHolder"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_go_to_today" />

            <com.estudiotrilha.inevent.view.NewTextView  
                android:id="@+id/textEventDuration"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textEventName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageCalendar"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#555"
                inevent:textFor="small"
                android:text="MAI 05-11, 2014" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_below="@+id/textEventName"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textEventPlace"
                android:contentDescription="@string/facebookHolder"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_place" />

            <com.estudiotrilha.inevent.view.NewTextView 
                android:layout_below="@+id/textEventName"
                android:id="@+id/textEventPlace"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#555"
                inevent:textFor="small"
                android:text="Lisbon, Portugal" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In that `ListView`, will be placed several items with images.

Here is a sample of the real deal:

[image: Sample item]

The problem is that all images are loaded asynchronously.

I am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/) to load those images.

What should I do to optimise the list?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem?  What and **why** are you trying to optimise?

Comment: @AleksG I'm trying to optimise the layout hoping that the ListView scrolls fluently, since I've already done everything I could on UIL.

The list stills skips about 40 frames when I scroll fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling fast is known as 'flinging', and it will naturally be quite intensive on a list that loads images dynamically (from web or local store), so the only way to deal with it on a mobile platform is to

a) improve user experience by adding a temporary 'loading image:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub) // resource or drawable
    .build();
```

b) Simply do not attempt any process intensive rendering when a fling is occuring. The screen moves too fast for anything useful to be rendered anyway, so you might as well wait until the screen is not moving before attempting to render anything:

```
boolean pauseOnScroll = false; // or true
boolean pauseOnFling = true; // or false
PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, pauseOnScroll, pauseOnFling);
listView.setOnScrollListener(listener);
```

Comment: nevermind, the problem was that I was doing a query on getView() everytime.